# Appium iOS get contexts not working

Tags: javascript, ios, selenium, react-native, appium

I am developing an iOS React-Native app. Right now I am working on integration tests for the login functionality. In order to login to our app, user needs to open email and click a link.

What I am trying to do with the Appium integration test:
- Open native app.
- Press button in app to send email
- Open browser and gmail
- Find email and click the link to login
- Return to app to do rest of testing

However I am having issues with opening the email, and I assume this is because the driver has the wrong context. However when I try to fetch available contexts with the `driver.contexts()` function, I just get an error and no contexts at all.

**Why is `driver.contexts()` function not working? Is what I'm trying to do reasonable?**

Stub of my test looks like this:

```
import wd from 'wd'
import { config, port } from '../appiumConfig'

const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote('localhost', port)

describe('Login', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => await driver.init(config))
  afterAll(async () => await driver.quit())

  it('Should get contexts', async () => {
    await driver.contexts((err, handle) => {
      if (err) { // Error!
        console.log(err)
      }
      console.log(handle)
    })
  })
})
```

And Appium config like this:

```
"ios-emulator": {
    "platformName": "iOS",
     "platformVersion": "11.3",
     "deviceName": "iPhone Simulator",
     "app": "./ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/myApp.app"
   }
```

Error I get is:

> {"message":"[contexts()] Error response status: 13, , UnknownError -
>   An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Selenium error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing
>   the command. Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   ::1:27753","status":13,"cause":{"status":13,"value":{"message":"An
>   unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   ::1:27753"},"sessionId":"a55f921f-b98c-4304-bc8d-cf3af1a48cd4"},"jsonwire...

Function documentation: https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/get-contexts/

Appium: 1.7.2

Mac: 10.13.4

Platform version: 11.3

Driver: XCUITest

Node: 8.10.0

npm: 3.8.6

EDIT: Here are also the errors that I get on the Appium server:

```
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"11.3","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator","app":"./ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MeruHealth.app","udid":"DD7881BD-3D0A-4C5B-8774-993954C6D349"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 8543 ms - 467
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/f43492eb-baa3-40b3-88b4-9aea2745ff7b/contexts
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getContexts() with args: ["f43492eb-baa3-40b3-88b4-9aea2745ff7b"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'getContexts'
[debug] [iOS] Getting list of available contexts
[debug] [iOS] Retrieving contexts and views
[debug] [iOS] Selecting by url: false 
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received app, but no match was found. Trying again.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current applications available:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:27890'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:27890"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "Meru Health"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "com.meruhealth.MeruHealthApp"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageDict: []
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:27890' for bundle 'com.meruhealth.MeruHealthApp'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Trying out the possible app ids: PID:27890
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Selecting app PID:27890 (try #20 of 20)
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardGetListing:' message to remote debugger
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Receiving data from remote debugger: '{"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:27890","WIRListingKey":{"1":{"WIRPageIdentifierKey":1,"WIRTitleKey":"JSContext","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeJavaScript"}}},"__selector":"_rpc_applicationSentListing:"}'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received response from socket send: '["PID:27890",{"1":{"WIRPageIdentifierKey":1,"WI...'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: {"1":{"WIRPageIdentifierKey":1,"WIRTitleKey":"JSContext","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeJavaScript"}}
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received app, but no match was found. Trying again.
[RemoteDebugger] Error: Could not connect to a valid app after 20 tries.
[RemoteDebugger]     at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:78:13)
[RemoteDebugger]     at RemoteDebugger.selectApp$ (../../lib/remote-debugger.js:277:6)
[RemoteDebugger]     at tryCatch (/Users/valtterilaine/meruhealth-app/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
[RemoteDebugger]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/valtterilaine/meruhealth-app/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
[RemoteDebugger]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/valtterilaine/meruhealth-app/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
[RemoteDebugger]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Users/valtterilaine/meruhealth-app/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[RemoteDebugger]     at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for me with native app

wd.js v1.6.1

appium server v1.7.2

node v7.9.0

npm v4.2.0

Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Code is similar to yours:

```
const wd = require('wd')

const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote(server)
await driver.init(desired)
const contexts = await driver.contexts()
```

Server logs:

```
> CALL init({"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"11.1","deviceName":"iPhone SE","automationName":"XCUITest","noReset":true,"app":"/Users/dmitry/Downloads/Nigeria-TEST.app"}) 
> POST /session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"11.1","deviceName":"iPhone SE","automationName":"XCUITest","noReset":true,"app":"/Users/dmitry/Downloads/Nigeria-TEST.app"}}
Driving the web on session: 425b04c9-3f26-4f67-bd2e-f955ada0abbd
> RESPONSE init({"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"11.1","deviceName":"iPhone SE","automationName":"XCUITest","noReset":true,"app":"/Users/dmle/Downloads/test.app"}) "425b04c9-3f26-4f67-bd2e-f955ada0abbd",{"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"11.1","deviceName":"iPhone SE","automationName":"XCUITest","noReset":true,"app":"/Users/dmle/Downloads/test.app","udid":"2CA85561-B4B9-4C59-A83A-E197ADD4E0C8"}
> CALL contexts() 
> GET /session/:sessionID/contexts 
> RESPONSE contexts() ["NATIVE_APP"]
```

Error in your log states `ECONNREFUSED` meaning your appium service was down, probably it was crashed on processing request -> check the full log to understand what was going on.

I would say that problem is most likely because you are trying to do all the steps in same session (reusing same driver instance).
Try to do browser navigation to gmail in separate session, and then back to using 1st one to continue with app testing. Multiple apps sessions started working with XCode 9, so it might help.